# Mouse disappears when I touch my screen

Tags: windows, mouse

I am having an issue regarding the mouse pointer. when I engage the touch screen, the mouse pointer disappears. Only when I move the mouse will the pointer emerge.

Is a setting to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If you read the [python] tag, you will notice that question is off topic. As far as the rest, we can try to help if you tell us what brand and model, as well as what version of Windows.

Comment: The closest thing I know of is the solution here, but it only pertains to typing on a keyboard, not touch.  I tried:  http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1656322/windows-mouse-cursor-disappearing.html  I don't think there is a Windows setting that is going to do what you want.  It would involve a regedit would be my guess, or possibly 3rd party software.